# kotlin file doesn't support flowchart written by markdown?

Tags: markdown, kotlin, flowchart

I'm using kotlin to develope android app. We know kotlin uses markdown to document its code. So I try to draw a flowchart by markdown syntax as below:

````
/**
 * Created by zhangruofan on 16-3-2.
 *
 * ```flow
 * st=>start: Start|past:>http://www.google.com[blank]
 * e=>end: End:>http://www.google.com
 * op1=>operation: My Operation|past
 * op2=>operation: Stuff|current
 * sub1=>subroutine: My Subroutine|invalid
 * cond=>condition: Yes
 * or No?|approved:>http://www.baidu.com
 * c2=>condition: Good idea|rejected
 * io=>inputoutput: catch something...|request
 *
 * st->op1(right)->cond
 * cond(yes, right)->c2
 * cond(no)->sub1(left)->op1
 * c2(yes)->io->e
 * c2(no)->op2->e
 * ```
 */
````

but the flowchart doesn't show.Some other markdown syntax such as `**Bold**` does work. I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Flowchart isn't a construction inherent to markdown syntax like `*bold*` is. Please explain why do you expect it to be supported?

Comment: I wanna use the diagram to show the structre of my class. When people take a look of the class, they can have a clear sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

As Ilya said, markdown doesn't have support for flowchart construction. What you are doing is telling markdown (specifically GitHub flavored markdown in this case) to render preformatted text and highlight it according to the syntax of `flow` language.

If you have an environment where your above code actually shows a chart, it's custom functionality in that environment, and you shouldn't expect it anywhere else.

The markdown that Kotlin supports is [documented here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#inline-markup) (basically [vanilla markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) with some extensions for linking to different bits of code).

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, do you have some environment where that snippet would actually render a chart?

Comment: I'm using `Cmd MarkDown`, the flowchart syntax works on it.

Comment: That's interesting. I've never seen that one before. But it has a number of extensions that normal markdown does not offer (like the charting and math syntax). Kotlin supports more vanilla markdown. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html